# Armadillo function eig_sym() not working

Tags: c++, armadillo, eigenvalue

I am trying to find the eigenvalues of a square matrix using the function ***eig_sym*** from the Armadillo linear algebra library:

```
mat STRESS = Mat<double>(3, 3, fill::zeros);
vec principals;

/**
   Populate STRESS with symmetric values
   from a stress tensor history named "stressTensor"
**/

STRESS(0,0) = stressTensor[XX].data[0];
STRESS(0,1) = stressTensor[XY].data[0];
STRESS(0,2) = stressTensor[XZ].data[0];
STRESS(1,0) = stressTensor[XY].data[0];
STRESS(1,1) = stressTensor[YY].data[0];
STRESS(1,2) = stressTensor[YZ].data[0];
STRESS(2,0) = stressTensor[XZ].data[0];
STRESS(2,1) = stressTensor[YZ].data[0];
STRESS(2,2) = stressTensor[ZZ].data[0];

eig_sym(principals, STRESS); // Code fails here
```

I get the ***std::logic_error*** message, which according to the Armadillo Doc means that the matrix ***STRESS*** is not square, even though it is demonstrably square.

I have even run the example code from the Armadillo Doc:

```
// for matrices with real elements

mat A = randu<mat>(50,50);
mat B = A.t()*A;  // generate a symmetric matrix

vec eigval;
mat eigvec;

eig_sym(eigval, eigvec, B);
```

This also produces the ***std::logic_error*** message.

I feel like I'm missing something very simple because I can't even get the example code to work. Include directory is set up correctly as I have no issue using ***arma::*** functions elsewhere in my project.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Louis Vallance

**EDIT 24/10/14 @1316GMT:**
I think the error is caused by the fact that I don't have LAPACK configured. I was under the impression that Armadillo comes with LAPACK and openBLAS pre-compiled. How can I configure my project to link with LAPACK if I only installed Armadillo?

Comment: See the README.txt file that comes with Armadillo

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

- Change the config file inside armadillo_bits and  uncomment the following lines `#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK` and `#define ARMA_USE_BLAS`
- http://ylzhao.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/blas-lapack-precompiled-binaries-for.html this link will help to download the precompiled version of blas and LAPACK libraries download release version 32 bit depending on your mingW bit installation
- Inside the project place the folder
- Go to project properties > c++ build > mingw c++ linker > under tool setting set the name of libraries without the lib extension
- Add the library search path and select from the work space option
- Place the dll files of those libraries in the project folder

This should be good enough to run